# PHP Manual .chm index functionality not working as expected

Tags: php, chm

When I started working with PHP (like 10 years ago) the main thing that won me over, is the manual in .chm format. I used to keep the "Index" tab open, and type in there anything I needed and it'll direct me to a nice, concise but exhaustive reference page.

Now, today, I wanted to refresh my memory with some of the properties of isset(), so I typed it in the Index, but nothing relevant appeared. See for yourself in the screenshot below.

I had to find the page through the "Search" tab, which is less convenient.

I've noticed a similar issue before, but I ignored it.
So, before posting a bug report or php.net, anyone knows what's happening here? Am I the only one with this problem, or is this another one of PHP's "improvements"?

[image: PHP manual (.chm) version after typing "isset" in the Index search box]

Comment: Downloaded the file right now, same problem. Tried the english and the german chm. I suppose they somehow tagged the `isset` article the wrong way so it doesn't appear in the index.
So, I'd say, the chm is not complete. You may search directly on their website, though (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) which is quite convenient. If you're online, that is.

Comment: It also happened with strtr() and I have the feeling I'll find many other functions missing in the index if I try...
The CHM is more convenient because it can be kept in a smaller window, can be directly called from the taskbar (under Windows), and is substantially faster, especially on dodgy connections like mine.
Thanks anyway! I'm relieved (and deceived at the same time) to know that it's not a unique problem with my setup.

Comment: Perhaps you can download the html offline documentation; I never tried working with it, but perhaps you can search there too. You could open these html docs in a separate browser window (or even a completely other browser to distinguish between the help and your normal work) and then taskswitch there, too.

Comment: This is a doc bug, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64842, I have this problem in the newest version too

Comment: But not problem when I using a 2012 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug. please vote on it, hopefully it'll get fixed.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64842

Comment: Thank you!
That's a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `index` doesn't include [Variable handling Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php).

I guess thats because `isset()`, `unset()`, `empty()`, etc are not actual php functions but language constructs, and are therefor not included in the index.

Another reason they are different is because they cannot be called with [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Comment: What about strtr()? It doesn't show up either.
Are you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ok, so they definitly forgot to include certain parts. `strstr` is part of the string functions (http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and none of them show up. But if you use the index to find `string` and click `String operators`, there is a reference to the `string functions` which is also broken. So it doesnt look like its intended.

Answer (score 0):

Index is created automatically on CHM files.
It uses a keyword in a page to make its entry in index.

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082423/can-an-index-be-created-for-a-chm-file), if you want more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here you could download an older version of the php manual in chm format.

If you have Windows XP or better you should right click on the chm and press the unlock button.

http://www.putlocker.com/file/DF8ED2618E418D83